# How to Set default value of CHECK BOX in J2ME

Tags: java-me, checkbox, default-value

I have created the Check box in J2ME and I want default value of all check box as true please suggest some code for it

Comment: Down voters don't be too harsh on newbies instead Help them learn the standards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ChoiceGroup..

```
ChoiceGroup cg = new ChoiceGroup("sample",ChoiceGroup.MULTIPLE); 
 // add some choices to the group using cg.append()
boolean array = new boolean[cg.size()];
// initialize all the elements of array to true..
cg.setSelectedFlags(array);
// do more processing
```

Hope this might help, for more details see [javaDocs](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Choice.html),

Comment: and next time try to be more specific in your questions.. i suggest read FAQ before posting... or at least visit some questions..